# Does Visual Studio Pro come with SQL Server?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I'm looking to upgrade from the Express editions and I was wondering if Visual Studio Pro edition came with SQL server 2008 R2 developer edition.

Thanks.

Comment: it includes tools like Server Explorer and integration with Microsoft SQL Server

Comment: FYI: You can use Sql Express with Visual Studio Pro as well i.e. you don't need to upgrade that if not needed.

Comment: Have a look at this chart: http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/product-comparison  That will show you what you can get with each level of Visual Studio depending on how much you want to spend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, you have to buy them separately, but you can work with [SQL Express](http://www.microsoft.com/express/Database/) in the meantime.

Edit: I don't know why but SQL Server 2008 r2 Dev edition is just $47.99 on [amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B003KWQBQ2).
and also SQL Server 2008 R2 Developer [can easily be upgraded to](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143393.aspx) SQL Server 2008 R2 Enterprise, web, standard etc., without reinstallation.

Edit 2: Ok, as @Infotekka says, **YES** it is included on the MSDN Subscription with some other software which comes in the purchase of VS2010 Pro :)

Comment: Not true, even the base Visual Studio Pro version comes with MSDN Essentials, which includes SQL Server Developer Edition: http://www.amazon.com/Microsoft-C5E-00521-Visual-Studio-Professional/dp/B0038KTO8S/ref=sr_1_2?s=software&ie=UTF8&qid=1300820796&sr=1-2

Comment: it says it includes MSDN Essentials Subscription wich includes a SQL Server 2008 R2, but it doesn't says wich version of SQL Server 2088 R2 it includes, if you can confirm its Developer edition then we all can go out of this mistake :)

Comment: Honestly I can only derive the answer from this(http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/product-comparison), but I have the Pro version with MSDN (one step up from Essentials) and it came with the developer version of SQL Server, Server 2008 R2 Standard, and Windows 7 Ultimate.  If you look at that chart, those three items are on the same line and checked for both editions.

Answer (score 2):

**YES.**

*If* you buy [Visual Studio 2010 Professional with MSDN](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/professional) it comes with SQL Server 2008 Developer Edition, along with developer licenses for several other editions of SQL Server, Windows, and Windows Server.

This is the edition I bought and have sitting on my desk in front of me, it includes media for:

- Visual Studio 2010 Professional
- Windows 7 Ultimate
- Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard
- Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Developer

Again, those are developer licenses.  You also have download access to ISOs for older versions of each though MSDN.

Answer (score 0):

the Visual studio 2010 installation comes with the following: C#, Visual basic, C++ and sql server express 2008 R2 engine (you can customize the installation to only install 1 Language + SQLSR2). It does not come with the sql management tool though (given you can do almost everything from the VS main IDE)

If you need it, you can download the server management tool (any will work for any SQL Server Engine) and as stated before, upgrades are sequential withou need to reinstall.

Answer (score 0):

The basic levels used to come with SQL Server Developer Edition.  With SQL Server 2012 and above, these are no longer included in the Visual Studio Professional (MPN) level.

It appears that Microsoft would rather that Visual Studio developers target another platform.

While you can use the express edition if you start to debug client databases in excess of the 10GB limit you are stuck and will be unable to restore them.